# SQL query returning wrong data, very strange

Tags: mysql, sql

So I have a query that seems to work fine up until this line `WHERE s.status = 'pending'` it is returning data `'closed'`. There are only 3 options for this data section pending, closed and live.

I have no idea why this is doing this, I use the same query but have `status = 'closed'` on a different section of the page (underneath this query so variables shouldnt be conflicting), so why would this be acting this way now?

```
SELECT s.gameid, s.gameday, s.hometeam AS hid, ht.teamname AS homename, s.awayteam AS aid, at.teamname AS awayname, s.status
FROM schedule s
  INNER JOIN teams ht ON s.hometeam = ht.teamid
  INNER JOIN teams at ON s.awayteam = at.teamid
WHERE s.status = 'pending' AND s.hometeam = $tid OR s.awayteam = $tid ORDER BY s.gameday ASC LIMIT 5
```

Comment: When mixing `AND` and `OR`'s, use `()`'s to make clear what should always be true, and what is optional.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wrap the `OR`'d parts in the `WHERE` clause in parenthesis.

```
WHERE s.status = 'pending' AND (s.hometeam = $tid OR s.awayteam = $tid) 
ORDER BY s.gameday ASC LIMIT 5
```

Your original query is effectively:

```
WHERE (s.status = 'pending' AND s.hometeam = $tid) OR s.awayteam = $tid
```

which is obviously incorrect. If you look at [MYSQL's operator precedence](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/operator-precedence.html), `AND` takes priority over `OR`.